# Connect to Postgres via ssh tunnel

Tags: postgresql, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have an access to database only from remote server.
That means I have ssh access to `remote_server`
And I have psql access from `remote_server` to `database_server`
I don't have ssh access from `remote_server` to `database_server` (It's Amazon RDS)

How can I connect to my database from localhost?
I know that I can establish ssh tunnel from `localhost` to `remote_server` like this:
`ssh -fN -L 9997:localhost:9996 ubuntu@remote_server`

So after this I want to connect `remote_server:9996` port with `database_server:5432` port.
How can I establish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set the remote port as `database_server:5432`.

This should do the trick:

```
ssh -L 9997:database_server:5432 ubuntu@remote_server
```

Requests to `localhost:9997` will be forwarded to `database_server:5432` through the tunnel on `remote_server`

Comment: the database is on another server, not on `remote_server`

Comment: @Snobby that's exactly why you need to specify database_server as the ip of the remote port

Comment: for further reading about ssh port forwarding: https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling-example (see Local Forwarding chapter, at the bottom there is an example very similar to my solution)

Comment: oh, it works! Thanks man, I misread the answer at first

Comment: You're welcome, glad I was of help